# How to add divider/separator between menu groups?

Tags: android, android-menu, separator, divider

I am trying to show a divider between each menu group. I have already tried to give each group an unique ID, but that didn't work. I have found some other solutions but they seem a little bit odd, like creating a LinearLayout with 1dp of height.

Here is how it is being shown. [image: menu without group dividers]

Here is the code for the MENU xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.marcelofb.cratediggersguide.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/searchOptions"
    android:title="Tools"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
    app:showAsAction="always">


<group
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupNovoUsado"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/novo"
        android:title="NOVO"
        app:showAsAction="never" >
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/usado"
        android:title="USADO"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>


<group
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupCompactoLP"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/compacto"
        android:title="COMPACTO"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/longplay"
        android:title="LP"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>


<group
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupNacionalImportado"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nacional"
        android:title="NACIONAL"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/importado"
        android:title="IMPORTADO"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>

</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

Hmm, they added a util method from Android 22.1.0.
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuCompat

```
MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(Menu menu, boolean enabled)
```

**Kotlin** style

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.what_ever, menu)
        MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(menu, true)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

    }

implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01"
```

Comment: Thank you @Catluc for the answer, just saved me! 
Addition: if you are using a PopupMenu just do it this way:
`MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(popup.getMenu(), true);`

Comment: This is so weird. I can't seem to resolve that method on Xamarin Android even with the support libraries imported.

Comment: @masterwok, You must add this line.
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
  in gradle.
But the dividers in the menu did not appear.

Answer (score -2):

```
<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="Second category">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_1"
            android:title="menu 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_2"
            android:title="menu 2" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

This way all the item ie - communication , second category will be shown in different group divided by line

Comment: Hello, this code creates different menus inside the options menu. I want to display all the options directly on the options menu. And even when implementing different menus it still doesn't show the dividers. But I appreciate your help!